# Issue with browser = Browser('firefox') part of my code

Tags: python, windows, selenium, firefox, splinter

I am running updated versions of my all modules within my python. I am using conda-forge and spyder 3.7.

I am just attempting to open a webpage using some basic code and I get stuck there.

I have searcher just about everywhere on the site, but I am not sure what I should do since I am quite new to this.

I have updated the modules I am using and continued after every update but it was to no avail.

Here is my code:

```
from splinter import Browser
browser = Browser('firefox')
browser.visit('https://google.com')
```

Previously written as:

```
from splinter import Browser
browser = Browser()
browser.visit('https://google.com')
```

Same issue with both.

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-12-71643798329a>", line 2, in <module>
    browser = Browser('firefox')

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/splinter/browser.py", line 53, in Browser
    return driver(*args, **kwargs)

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/splinter/driver/webdriver/firefox.py", line 33, in __init__
    self.driver = Firefox(firefox_profile)

  File "C:\Users\lkerzabi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)

  File "C:\Users\lkerzabi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)

  File "C:\Users\lkerzabi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)

  File "C:\Users\lkerzabi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

  File "C:\Users\lkerzabi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

I expect to be able to open a webpage, but it just gives me this error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this issue from Github [Selenium 3.4.0 Unable to find matching capabilities](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3884) ?

Particularly those two answers:

- [First option](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3884#issuecomment-441594636)
- [Second option](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3884#issuecomment-297377353)

Seems like you are experiencing the same issue